# Flutter Android 12 exported="false" Error

Tags: android, flutter, build, manifest, pubspec

I made a new app and I'm in the process of uploading it to google play store. But I am getting exported="false" error. I tried many ways but couldn't. I updated most of the packages in the pubspec file to the latest version, but still the false value did not return to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you had updated all pubs to latest version then you need to update your compileSDKVersion to 33 and for that you need to specify in your project's Android Maniifest file and make launcher activity to be "android:exported"="false" as per [this](https://cafonsomota.medium.com/android-12-dont-forget-to-set-android-exported-on-your-activities-services-and-receivers-3bee33f37beb)

Comment: I did what you said first, but the merge-manifest tab does not appear in android studio, and I don't understand which activity should I give false value, sorry.

Comment: android:name=".MainActivity" should be android:exported="true" you can check it here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#merge-manifests